# Button Click Count-Reset & Repeat

Tags: jquery, html, css, onclick, click

Is there anyone who can help me with this. I am playing arround with one small button project.

I am using css button but lets say an button from here. "example: http://www.cssbuttongenerator.com/"

Now lets say, when someone click on the button it will write below the button 1...
If someone click again it will write 2... No matter who will click. Me, you or someone third. It will count and remember number of clicked times.

Now lets say it counts to 100, so 100 persons can click on it. After that it resets to 0 and start counting clicks again.

It must be possible. Jquery or whatever is required, please help this newb (me).

Even use an input button or an image or whatever... Just to count and remember clicks. Thank you , awaiting for some great answers!

Comment: you can make use of cookies set them using javascript and on button click read the value of that cookie

Comment: That sounds good. I thought of jquery and jquery cookie but I don't know to set it up. I just know html and css :) ! Learning tho... But jquery seems more advanced for start...

Comment: see my answer i posted a link which explains simple operation on cookies using javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can make use of cookies set them using javascript and on button click read the value of that cookie
for more information on manipulating cookies using javascript please go through [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).
[Here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3470821/So-You-Want-To-Set-A-Cookie-Huh.htm) is also an other link that explains how to store the value in cookies using javascript

**UPDATE**

your solution is possible without cookies too if you don't want to persist the counter between different request to the page and for a single user
i made a fiddle please see [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/FB8xA/4/) 
i hope it will help

**UPDATE 2**

your

```
No matter who will click
```

This is only possible when you are working with any server side technology like asp.net,Java/jsp/PHP because the cookie based solution will not fit your need in that case .if you wish that anyone click and every time is should incereament the counter no matter who clicked it then you **have to USE** server side Sessions.

**UPDATE**

in jquery onDOMReady meand when the document/page loads completely then only the scripts will run so its error safe way of registering the script with the page
anyways
I used jquery styled click handlers for buttons if you are not using jquery then you can simple call count function on button onclick event

if you are using jquery then you can write it like this

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var x = 0;    
    function resetcounter() {
    x = 0;
    document.getElementById("counting").value = x;
    }

   function count() {
   if(x<50)
    {
      x += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        x=0;
    }
    document.getElementById("counting").value = x;
   }
   $('#btn').click(

         function() {
         count();
    });

    $('#reset').click(

    function() {
           resetcounter();
    });  
});
```

Comment: I will try to play with it... Doesnt seems easy! Will confirm if I get it working.

Comment: that's great meanwhile if i will get time will try to post a fiddle :)

Comment: Okay let's say screw the "No matter who will click". Your fiddle works great but you have also made reset button for the count... Can it count to a specified number 50 for example and automatically resets on 51st click?

Comment: just add a check on x<50 and if not set x to 0 see my updated fiddle now

Comment: Flawless! Thank you very much Devjosh.

Comment: Doesn't this yield a distinct and separate count for each "someone" using the page? I did not interpret the original question this way. I must be wrong though :-/